# How can I print the first letter of each word of a string?

Tags: python, string, printing, output

I am new to Python and I want to experiment more with string manipulation.

I would like to print the first letter of each word of the statement...

```
'I like sweet and savoury food'
```

... so that the output looks like this:

```
'I l s a s f'
```

Comment: Yes, this is very useful! How would you put a space between each letter?

Answer (score 2):

A simple "pythonic" way to do this is

```
print(' '.join(word[0] for word in sentence.split()))
```

---

Having a `for` loop like this is called a list comprehension. You can write it out in full detail:

```
split = sentence.split()
result = ''
for word in split:
    result += word[0] + ' '
print(result.strip()) # strip to get rid of trailing space
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!